# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^n_{k=1}{c^n}{x_{n-k+1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

So I am considering $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^n_{k=1} c^nx_{n-k+1}$, where $c<1$ is a constant, and $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence convergence to $0$.

Can you prove that the limit above exist? I was trying to show the sequence is increasing and bound but it leads to nowhere.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $x_n$ is in nominator or denominator?

Comment: sorry I edited. x_n is nominator

Comment: I assume you should add the assumption that $c>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Outline: the assumptions imply

- there exists $B$ such that $|x_n| \le B$ for all $n$;
- for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N(\varepsilon)$ such that $|x_m| < \varepsilon$ for all $m\ge N(\varepsilon)$;
- for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $K(\varepsilon)$ such that $0 < c^m < \varepsilon$ for all $m\ge K(\varepsilon)$.

Then consider, for $n\ge N(\varepsilon)+K(\varepsilon)$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n c^n x_{n-k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-N(\varepsilon)} c^n x_{n-k+1} + \sum_{k=n-N(\varepsilon)+1}^n c^n x_{n-k+1}.
$$
(Remember that a geometric series $\sum c^n$ is bounded by its first term times $1/(1-c)$.)

Comment: This one makes sense I think. Thank you!